# How to parse CSV data using contain based routing in apache camel DSL?

Tags: apache-camel, dsl

I am writing a route where DSL route reading different CSV file.
I am filtering CSV based on header and perform some action on it like unmarshaling.
My route:

```
CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();    

            //Route 1 for filter CSV based on header
            from("file:/home/r2/Desktop/csvFile?noop=true")
                .choice().when(body().contains("partyName"))
                    .to("direct:partyNameCSV")
                .when(body().contains("\"stuffName\""))
                    .to("direct:stuffNameCSV")
                .otherwise().endChoice();   

            //Route 2 partyNameCSV
            from("direct:partyNameCSV")
                .unmarshal(csv)
                .process(new PartyNameCSVProcessor())
                .end();

            //Route 3 stuffNameCSV
            from("direct:stuffNameCSV")
                .unmarshal(csv)
                .process(new StuffCSVProcessor())
                .end();
```

Output:Build Success but not invoking any processor

`[CSV.map.AutoCSV.main()] INFO      org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route1 started and consuming from: file:///home/r2/Desktop/csvFile?noop=true
[CSV.map.AutoCSV.main()] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route2 started and consuming from: direct://partyNameCSV
[CSV.map.AutoCSV.main()] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Route: route3 started and consuming from: direct://stuffNameCSV
[CSV.map.AutoCSV.main()] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Total 3 routes, of which 3 are started
[CSV.map.AutoCSV.main()] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.638 seconds
[CSV.map.AutoCSV.main()] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
[CSV.map.AutoCSV.main()] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Starting to graceful shutdown 3 routes (timeout 300 seconds)
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Route: route3 shutdown complete, was consuming from: direct://stuffNameCSV
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Route: route2 shutdown complete, was consuming from: direct://partyNameCSV
[Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - ShutdownTask] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy - Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: file:///home/r2/Desktop/csvFile?noop=true`

My question is where I am doing wrong or something else I am missing?

**UPDATE**:

file1.csv

`"partyName","partNumber"
"rajat temaniya","1"
"lalit kumar","2"`

file2.csv

`"stuffName","price"
"laptop","88000"
"mobile","50000"`

Comment: So have you actually put any data to trigger  your route?

Comment: Yes!! I update question

Comment: You need to convert your body to String before your choice (). Use convertBodyTo(String.class) before your choice.

Comment: Yehhh its work thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `convertBodyTo(String.class)` to convert your body before doing any content-based routing.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable streamcache so that the body is preserved for later usage and advise to convert the message to string.

```
from({{consumer}})
    .streamCaching()
    .to({{producer}});
```